# How do I call a matlab variable from an S function?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, simulink

I am working on an S function in simulink. There are some variables in the MATLAB workspace available. I want to call them.

So in MATLAB:

```
a=3;
```

and in the S function (written in C/C++):

```
double a = CallFromMATLABWorkSpace(a);  //Something like this.
```

How do I do this? There is something like `mexCallMATLAB` but it is not clear how I should use this in this situation.

Answer (score 6):

To get data from a workspace use the function [mexGetVariable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexgetvariable.html).

However, this is a somewhat unusual thing to do.
Why isn't the data being passed as a parameter to the S-Function?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the documentation for [`mexCallMATLAB`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html), as well as [interoping with C++ source code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-c-source-mex-files.html), it would look something like the following:

Let's say you have a MatLab function `MyDoubleFunction` that takes a single scalar double value and returns a scalar double value.  You would do the following if you wanted to pass the function a value of `4.0` and see what the answer is:

```
//setup the input args
mxArray* input_args[1] = {mxCreateDoubleScalar(4.0)};
mxArray** output_args; //will be allocated during call to mexCallMATLAB

//make the call to the Matlab function
if (mexCallMATLAB( 1 /* number of output arguments */,
                   output_args,
                   1 /* number of input arguments */,
                   &input_args,
                   "MyDoubleFunction"))
{
    //error if we get to this code block since it returned a non-zero value
}

//inspect the output arguments
double answer = mxGetScalar(*output_args);
```

Comment: Second and fourth arguments for mexCallMATLAB need to be of type mxArray *...[]. In your code they should have "&" in front of them.